# In a react native section list, is it ok to have duplicate keys if they are actually the same object?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a section list for sending a message to someone... section 1 is recents and section 2 is all friends. I'm getting the duplicate key error, because the recents are a subset of all friends, but the two objects are actually the same thing and that is the behavior I want. Is there any way to optimize this or tell the section list that it's ok?

[Example of my section list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIDKh.png)

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xVKL.png)

Just wanna make sure I'm optimizing for performance. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the same `key={value}` on more that one item you're removing the list's ability to optimise the UI elements when checking for changes. It doesn't matter if they are logically the same entity to *you*, they are different items in the list.

I'd recommend adding some kind of prefix: `recent-${id}` vs `friend-${id}`

Comment: Makes sense. Great idea. Thank you!

Comment: where to do that? keyExtractor?